# After applying PCA on my dataframe it give me a weird figure, how does it mean or how can I interpret it?

Tags: python, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I work with pokemon data and I have dataframe with only numerical value(stat, type, id, ...), this dataframe have about 12000 rows and each rows represent a fight between two pokemon. The last column of my dataframe is about the tiers of pokemon, I separate winner pokemon(winner of the match) in 3 tiers (top, middle, low) and then I apply PCA on the dataframe with the aim to observe cluster(one for each tier) on a plane.

Here is my code:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

features = ['id_pkmn1','id_pkmn2','id_type1_pkmn1','id_type2_pkmn1','id_type1_pkmn2',
            'id_type2_pkmn2','pv_1','atq_1','def_1','atqspe_1','defspe_1','spd_1',
            'pv_2','atq_2','def_2','atqspe_2','defspe_2','spd_2']
# Separating out the features
x = df_number.loc[:, features].values
# Separating out the target
y = df_number.loc[:,['tiers']].values
# Standardizing the features
x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents
             , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])
finalDf = pd.concat([principalDf, df_number[['tiers']]], axis = 1)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
ax.set_xlabel('Principal Component 1', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Principal Component 2', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('2 component PCA', fontsize = 20)
targets = ['toptier','middletier','lowtier']
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
for target, color in zip(targets,colors):
    indicesToKeep = finalDf['tiers'] == target
    ax.scatter(finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'principal component 1']
               , finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'principal component 2']
               , c = color
               , s = 50)
ax.legend(targets)
ax.grid()
```

here is the result:
[image]

My question is: How can I interpret it ? What does it mean ?

Comment: You are reducing all information about the Pokemon down to two principal components. This seems awkward. How does the ID of Pkm1 and the ID of Pkm2 explain the outcome of the fight? PCAs are not quite interpretable. You standardized the data and summarized information from each feature together into two. I believe the plot is more or less nonsense values that follows the standardized components of x with no real information content.

Comment: Do you have any proposition to help me to optimize this code to maybe find something better, for example you talk about pokemon id, I  think it's a good idea to keep them because it's represent the numerical value corresponding to the pokemon, so for example mewtwo is strong so there will have many fight with him as winner so the numerical value associated to mewtwo will appear many time so become important.

Comment: If everything is well done and well calculated, you could interpret that figure as that there is no clear feature or set of features that the pokemons of a certain tier have developed differently in comparison to the other tiers. However, that figure looks oddly symmetrical. Are you sure you have applied PCA correctly?

Comment: I believe one would have to know more about Pokémon in this case. If you say that the ID as a numerical value correlates with power, then it may seem suitable (that's new to me though). But anyway, PCs cannot be interpreted like the original values. I wonder why e.g. PC1=2 cannot be PC2=-4 oder -3. As Shinra said, it's remarkably symmetrical which looks as if something went wrong.

Comment: I'm not really sure if I use correctly the PCA, because I don't really know how to use it correctly and in which case. For example I don't know if it's the best model to apply on this dataframe, but I try to apply other model like: LLE, TNSE, MDS, and many other and no one give me a good figure, the PCA give me the more beautiful so I keep it, I was thinking that it geometrical structure could be more interesting to study.